# How to use ng-class for font family

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to use ng-class to apply font family in angularjs. Font family will be loaded from a dropdown

Comment: Same way you use font-family in any css

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a font family class according to your drop-down values like this

```
.exampleserif {
    font-family: Times, "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif;
}

.examplesansserif {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.examplemonospace {
    font-family: "Lucida Console", Courier, monospace;
}

.examplecursive {
    font-family: cursive;
}

.examplefantasy {
    font-family: fantasy;
}
```

and apply to body by ng-class directive by this way.

```
<body data-ng-class="{ 'exampleserif': dropdownvalues1, 'examplesansserif': dropdownvalues2 }">
```

There are many way to implement ng class from here `https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass`

Comment: If i use other language fonts.  For example Hindi,Tamil etc. In the controller I get the english words and not Tamil/Hindi But while typing in the textbox I get Tamil/Hindi

Comment: can you tell me your table design of your required pages? I think for this causes you need to setting a language key to every tables of database.